# query model.vo uma solução com jpql e subqueryes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Estou com a seguinte query no MySQL querendo passar para JPQL e estou com dúvida na sintaxe:

```
SELECT a2.produto , 
       a2.descricao, 
       a2.quantidade_recente, 
       Soma 
  from (SELECT p.codigoProduto, 
               sum(p.quantidade_recente) as Soma 
          from previsaovendas.produto  as p, 
               previsaovendas.usuario u 
         where u.codigo = p.codigo_filial 
           and u.codigo_chefe = 3 
         group by p.codigoProduto) as a1,
      (SELECT p1.codigoProduto as produto, 
              p1.descricao, 
              p1.quantidade_recente 
         from previsaovendas.produto as p1,  
              previsaovendas.usuario u
        where u.codigo = p1.codigo_filial 
          and u.codigo_chefe = 3 ) as a2
 where a2.produto = a1.codigoProduto;
```

Veja o [resultado na tela](https://snag.gy/cE4vWa.jpg)

A query em jpql que é :

```
String jpql1 = "select new br.com.previsao.model.vo.Filtro(a2.produto , a2.descricao, a2.quantidadeRecente, Soma)"
        + " (select p.codigoProduto, sum(p.quantidadeRecente) aS Soma  from Produto p where p.gerenteFilial.chefe.codigo =:codigo ) as a1,"
        + " (select p1.codigoProduto aS produto, p1.descricao, p1.quantidade_recente from Produto p1 where p1.gerenteFilial.chefe.codigo =:codigo ) as a2"
        + " where a2.produto = a1.codigoProduto";


 // metodo buscarPorPaginacao
 TypedQuery<Filtro> query = manager.createQuery(jpql1, Filtro.class);   
 query.setParameter("codigo", 3L);

 List<Filtro> resultado = query.getResultList(); 

 for (Filtro prod : resultado) {
      System.out.println(" Impressão Filtro da Empresa: ");
      System.out.println(" Nome : " + prod.getCodigoProduto() +  " Filtro " + prod.getDescricao()+  " Quantidade " + prod.getQuantidade()+ " Total " + prod.getTotal());

 }
```

recebo o erro no stack :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 99 [select new
>   br.com.previsao.model.vo.Filtro(a2.produto , a2.descricao,
>   a2.quantidadeRecente, Soma) (select p.codigoProduto,
>   sum(p.quantidadeRecente) aS Soma  from br.com.previsao.model.Produto p
>   where p.gerenteFilial.chefe.codigo =:codigo ) as a1, (select
>   p1.codigoProduto aS produto, p1.descricao, p1.quantidade_recente from
>   br.com.previsao.model.Produto p1 where p1.gerenteFilial.chefe.codigo
>   =:codigo ) as a2 where a2.produto = a1.codigoProduto]

Comment: parece que a jpql não aceita subquerye

Answer (score 1):

A consulta está incorreta, faltou uma vírgula bem no ponto onde o erro ocorre:

```
a2.descricao, a2.quantidadeRecente, Soma), (select p.
                                         ^
```

O JPQL no Hibernate aceita subqueries no `SELECT`, `WHERE` e no `HAVING`. Portanto, desde que a lógica da sua consulta esteja correta, é para funcionar.